# Is three hours enough for an international-domestic transfer at Delhi?

Tags: layovers, short-connections, del

My International flight will be reaching New Delhi IGI at 2:45 AM and I am planning to book a domestic flight at 5:45 AM.

Is three hours sufficient for me to move from International to Domestic?

I believe there must be a shuttle service inside the airport to transfer me from International to Domestic but still I don't know if Customs time at IGI could cause any delay or not.

Comment: What domestic airline are you planning to fly with?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**3 hours should be fine**, especially if you're flying on a major airline, since they fly domestic flights out of the same terminal as international flights (T3).  Only LCCs (SpiceJet, Indigo, GoAir) use T1.

If you do need to transfer, figure on 1 hour for customs and immigration, and assume you need to check in one hour early, which leaves you an hour -- sufficient, but doesn't leave you a whole lot of buffer if something/anything goes wrong.  Shuttle buses run [every 20 minutes](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/terminal-transfers.aspx), or if you're in a pinch you can take a taxi (~15 min).

In any case, if it's not too late, I'd recommend booking both your international and domestic flights on the same ticket, that way you're covered if you miss the connection.  Fog regularly causes [total chaos](http://articles.economictimes.indiatimes.com/2013-12-17/news/45296401_1_fog-delays-runway-visibility-required-visibility) at DEL, especially in winter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will be traveling via Indigo. Is October month considered to be causing fog related issues at IGI ?

Comment: October should still be fine, winter fog starts to kick in around December.

Comment: Thanks. I hope the cyclone "Hud Hud" doesn't create any trouble. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Advice from [Air India](http://www.airindia.in/delhi.htm) is:

[image: Air India]

While international flights arrive at T3, [domestic connections](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/terminal-transfers.aspx) may depart from T3 (Air India, Jet Airways, Vistara airlines) or from T1D (Indigo, Spice Jet & Go Air).

Journey time by free bus or paid cab between the two terminals is about [10 to 15 min](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g304551-i3482-k8307949-Transfer_time_between_T1_and_T3_at_Delhi_Airport-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_De.html).

So for T3 to T1 add 20 minutes for the bus schedule and 15 for the journey time.

Some of the bus schedule delay might be skipped if taking a taxi, for which there are two options, 'standard' (Mega or Meru Cab) and Delhi Police Pre-Paid cab for which people usually have to wait.